# How can I count the number of ways of selecting values on different rows based on a condition?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a table with a product name and price. How can I count the number of ways of choosing two products with a sum of an exact value?

Here's what I mean:

```
Product   Price
   1         5
   2         3
   3         8
   4         7
```

**From these, how many ways are there to choose two products that equal 10 in price?** I'm looking for unique sums and the count can be with the product itself. In this case, I should get a count of 2 (product 1 + product 1, product 2 + product 4).

I'm new to SQL and been stuck on this problem for hours. Massive thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use brute force. Self join the table to get all possible pairs and then just filter for the sum of prices being `10`.

```
SELECT t1.product,
       t2.product
       FROM elbat t1
            INNER JOIN elbat t2
                       ON t2.product >= t1.product
       WHERE t1.price + t2.price = 10;
```

If you want ordered pairs, i.e. `(n, m) <> (m, n)` when `n <> m`, you can just change the `INNER JOIN` to a `CROSS JOIN`.

```
SELECT t1.product,
       t2.product
       FROM elbat t1
            CROSS JOIN elbat t2
       WHERE t1.price + t2.price = 10;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=c475da75984cf104a930ed42e11bdf74)

Comment: Ah perfect, that solved it. Thanks a million!

Comment: @stickybit . . . The answer to the question would appear to be `count(*)` on the first query.